# How do I specify tox + python version specific requirements

Tags: python, pypy, tox

Currently I have the following:

```
[gh-actions]
python =
    3.7: py37
    3.8: py38
    3.9: py39
    3.10: py310
    pypy-3.7: pypy3
    pypy-3.8: pypy3

[tox]
minversion = 1.9
envlist =
    lint
    py{37,38,39,py3}-django22-{sqlite,postgres}
    py{37,38,39,310,py3}-django32-{sqlite,postgres}
    py{38,39,310,py3}-django40-{sqlite,postgres}
    py310-djangomain-{sqlite,postgres}
    docs
    examples
    linkcheck

toxworkdir = {env:TOX_WORKDIR:.tox}

[testenv]
deps =
    Pillow
    SQLAlchemy
    mongoengine
    django22: Django>=2.2,<2.3
    django32: Django>=3.2,<3.3
    django40: Django>=4.0,<4.1
    djangomain: https://github.com/django/django/archive/main.tar.gz
    py{37,38,39,310}-django{22,32,40,main}-postgres: psycopg2-binary
    py{py3}-django{22,32,40,main}-postgres: psycopg2cffi
```

I need to install a different `psycopg2` depending on `cpython` vs `pypy`. I've tried all kinds of combinations, and nothing, [it all ends in failure](https://github.com/kingbuzzman/factory_boy/actions). I can't get any of the `*-postgres` envs to install.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was never `tox` or `tox`'s configuration.

The issue was `github actions`, when you use `tox-environment` or `python-version` + `tox-environment`, `tox-gh-actions` won't parse it correctly. Causing it to never match.

[This is what I removed](https://github.com/kingbuzzman/factory_boy/commit/caecb860041e96aa7f5866850a64440cd2af48e5).
This is what [tox.ini looks like](https://github.com/kingbuzzman/factory_boy/blob/cc6c2eedaae6608c97155ff793b265b10ac1de61/tox.ini#L1-L34) and what [github actions looks like](https://github.com/kingbuzzman/factory_boy/blob/a381ed58df6cf219563d69ca12c0836063d00bff/.github/workflows/test.yml#L15-L21) [and line 47]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you do not run the correct environments in your GitHub Actions.

For example. In your `tox.ini` you create an env with the name:

```
py37-django22-alchemy-mongoengine-postgres
```

Then you define the requirements as following:

```
py{37,38,39,310}-postgres: psycopg2-binary
```

Which means - install `psycopg2-binary` when the env name contains the factors `py37` + `postgres`. This matches the above env! So far so good.

But in your gha your run:

```
- python-version: "3.7"
  tox-environment: django22-postgres
```

... which does not contain the `py37` factor - so no match - no installation.

The `sqlite` tests succeed as it `sqlite` comes along with Python.

I would suggest that you have a look at the django projects in the [jazzband github organization](https://github.com/jazzband). They all are heavy use of tox factors (the parts separated by dashes) and they also use gha - mostly via https://github.com/ymyzk/tox-gh-actions which I would recommend, too.

Basically you just run `tox` on gha and let the plugin do the heavy lifting of matching Python environments from tox to github.

Disclaimer:
I am one of the tox maintainers and you earn a prize for the most complex factor setup I have ever seen :-)

Comment: All this makes a lot of sense, ive simplified the configuration a lot, added `tox-gh-actions`, getting this on my latest run https://github.com/kingbuzzman/factory_boy/runs/6315865329?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: I dare say I found the solution, thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote or if you accept the answer :-)